# Make jquery transition smoother on mobile browser?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

Okay im making a mobile application using jquery, and then im using phonegap to run it on android, but the transitions are choppy and slow, does anyone have any recommendations for speeding up jquery animations? Thanks :)

Comment: Are the animations slow in your browser? Sounds like your device cannot cope with the animation for whatever reason. I've never tested it with PhoneGap, but looking into CSS transitions may be an option as they're hardware accelerated and perform better on mobile.

Comment: There fast in my browser (chrome) but when i compile them into a app and run it on my phone (droid x) it runs more slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All jQuery animation effects can given a duration value in order to speed up or slow down the effect:

```
$('div.container').fadeIn('fast');  // Shortcut for 200 milliseconds
$('div.container').fadeIn('slow');  // Shortcut for 600 milliseconds
$('div.container').fadeIn();        // Default value of 400 milliseconds
$('div.container').fadeIn(100);     // Specify whatever value you want.
```

Comment: There going at the right speed, its simply they are choppy, and the whole broswer flashes white when you click on a link with a transition.

Comment: Sounds like a limitation of bad hardware or a browser that can't handle the animation. Sorry I misunderstood your question. You should have titled it "Make jQuery transitions smoother on mobile browser".

Answer (score 0):

You should add a argument in milliseconds to the animation function